# Encoding latin1 to UTF8 in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I have a legacy MySQL database with `latin1` encoding, and new MySQL database with `utf-8` encoding. When I migrate the data from the legacy to new one, the strings returned and rendered in webpages contains weird characters.

example: â¥Chocolate biscuitâ¢

There's a model that connects to the old database to get the records, and use a rake task to map the old records and create new records

```
class LegacyDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection(
    adapter:  "mysql2",
    database: "old_database",
    encoding: "latin1"
  )
end
```

I referred to [this website](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/12/07/solving-latin1-and-utf8-errors-for-good-in-ruby.html) to solve the encoding problems, but the fallback hash is hardcoded. I need a dynamic one so that I don't need to add the fallbacks each time when a loop that fixes encoding is called.

```
def fix_encoding(str)

  # Referring to the solution from the website
  new_str = str.encode('cp1252',:fallback => {
    "\u0080" => "\x80".force_encoding("cp1252"),
    "\u0081" => "\x81".force_encoding("cp1252"),
    "\u008D" => "\x8D".force_encoding("cp1252"),
    "\u008F" => "\x8F".force_encoding("cp1252"),
    "\u0090" => "\x90".force_encoding("cp1252"),
    "\u009D" => "\x9D".force_encoding("cp1252"),
    "\u0098" => "\x98".force_encoding("cp1252"),
    "\u0099" => "\x99".force_encoding("cp1252")
  }).force_encoding("utf-8")
  return new_str
end
```

I want to change it to be dynamic, but I failed to convert it.

```
# How to do it in dynamic?
new_str = str.encode('cp1252', :fallback => Proc.new { |v| "#{v[4..5]}".force_encoding("cp1252") }).force_encoding("utf-8")
```

Or is there any other solution to fix the encoding problem?

Comment: So you probably haven't migrated the database correctly, and/or you're not connecting to your new database correctly...? "Fixing" this should involve correctly handling encodings to/from the database, not some manual conversion.

Comment: @deceze How to handle the encodings correctly to/from the database? I'm not familiar with database encodings..